# Names for sequences of specific length

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Do sequences of specific lengths have names, like tuples have [1]?

*Edit (added)*: Background: Although "a tuple is a sequence" [2,3], Tuple names typically end with "-uple", which may not be intuitive to read if the surrounding text only refers to sequences and not tuples. Especially if the reader is not familiar with the concept of tuples. Hence, using tuple names for sequences may not be optimal for readibility.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Names_for_tuples_of_specific_lengths
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple
[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence

Comment: What difference do you see between a tuple and a sequence?  The article you link to says "an n-tuple is a sequence (or ordered list) of n elements"

Comment: "A sequence requires each element to be of the same type.
A tuple can have elements with different types."  From: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122595/whats-the-difference-between-tuples-and-sequences